# How can I return a list of records based on contiguous time assignments in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql, t-sql, time, sql-server-2000

I have a Table that looks like this:

```
IP            Hostname   TransactionDate
------------- ---------- -------------------
1.1.1.1       A          2009-01-01 01:00:00
1.1.1.1       A          2009-01-02 01:00:00
1.1.1.1       A          2009-01-03 01:45:00
1.1.1.1       B          2009-01-04 01:00:00
1.1.1.1       A          2009-01-05 01:00:00
```

I would like to build a query to return records that will group results based on how long they've contiguously held an IP address:

ie (selecting or IP 1.1.1.1):

```
Hostname    GrantDate            ExpireDate
----------- ---------------      -----------------
A           2009-01-01 01:00:00  2009-01-04 01:00:00
B           2009-01-04 01:00:00  2009-01-05 01:00:00
A           2009-01-05 01:00:00  NULL
```

What's the best way to accomplish this task? I'd like to avoid cursors where possible. I'm using SQL Server 2000 which makes this more difficult...

Answer (score 1):

There are a few solutions to this problem in Joe Celko's [SQL Puzzles and Answers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123735963). Google has [an excerpt](http://books.google.com/books?id=krv8CUJU44sC&pg=PA234&lpg=PA234&dq=celko+contiguous+time&source=bl&ots=jkBHcDSyvj&sig=G9Lx595vqFVXSNesYti40nOiuE8&hl=en&ei=IseRSfreONW5tweC6u3bCw&sa=X&oi=book_result&resnum=3&ct=result#PPA234,M1) which includes them. His examples include start and end times, but it should be fairly simple to adapt them.

Comment: Thanks for the reference Tom. The examples in the book are quite different from what I'm trying to achieve, but they've helped point me in the right direction. I already have a solution that uses a cursor. I see that this question has been asked several times, just not quite in this manner.

Answer (score 0):

Posted for Posterity's sake. I just can't find a way to do this without using a cursor. Part of it, I'm sure, is that SQL is not my strong point. If anyone else runs across this post, here's the solution I've used. I'm going to keep plugging away at using a query for it and will post that if I ever figure it out.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @ip VARCHAR(15)
    SET @ip = '1.1.1.1'

DECLARE @dhcplog TABLE(IP VARCHAR(15), HOSTNAME VARCHAR(32), IPDATE DATETIME)
DECLARE @results TABLE(IP VARCHAR(15), HOSTNAME VARCHAR(32), STARTDATE DATETIME, ENDDATE DATETIME)
INSERT INTO @dhcplog VALUES('1.1.1.1', 'A', '2009-01-01 01:00:00')
INSERT INTO @dhcplog VALUES('1.1.1.1', 'A', '2009-01-02 02:00:00')
INSERT INTO @dhcplog VALUES('1.1.1.1', 'A', '2009-01-05 03:00:00')
INSERT INTO @dhcplog VALUES('1.1.1.1', 'B', '2009-01-07 04:00:00')
INSERT INTO @dhcplog VALUES('1.1.1.1', 'B', '2009-01-07 10:00:00')
INSERT INTO @dhcplog VALUES('1.1.1.1', 'B', '2009-01-08 05:00:00')
INSERT INTO @dhcplog VALUES('1.1.1.1', 'C', '2009-01-09 06:00:00')
INSERT INTO @dhcplog VALUES('1.1.1.1', 'A', '2009-01-10 07:00:00')

DECLARE @cHOST VARCHAR(32)
DECLARE @cEND DATETIME

DECLARE @tIP VARCHAR(15)
DECLARE @tHOST VARCHAR(32)
DECLARE @tIPDATE DATETIME

DECLARE IPCursor CURSOR FOR SELECT IP, HOSTNAME, IPDATE
                            FROM @dhcplog
                            WHERE IP = @ip
                            GROUP BY IP, HOSTNAME, IPDATE
                            ORDER BY IPDATE DESC

OPEN IPCursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM IPCursor INTO @tIP, @tHOST, @tIPDATE
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
            BEGIN
                IF @tHOST = @cHOST
                    BEGIN
                        UPDATE @results
                        SET STARTDATE = @tIPDATE
                        WHERE HOSTNAME = @cHOST
                        AND ENDDATE = @cEND
                    END
                ELSE
                    BEGIN
                        INSERT INTO @results (IP, HOSTNAME, STARTDATE, ENDDATE)
                        VALUES (@tIP, @tHOST, @tIPDATE, @tIPDATE)
                        SET @cHOST = @tHOST
                        SET @cEND = @tIPDATE
                    END
                FETCH NEXT FROM IPCursor INTO @tIP, @tHOST, @tIPDATE
            END
CLOSE IPCursor
DEALLOCATE IPCursor

SELECT * FROM @results

SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

**Results:**

```
IP      Hostname    StartDate       EndDate
1.1.1.1 A       2009-01-10 07:00:00 2009-01-10 07:00:00
1.1.1.1 C       2009-01-09 06:00:00 2009-01-09 06:00:00
1.1.1.1 B       2009-01-07 04:00:00 2009-01-08 05:00:00
1.1.1.1 A       2009-01-01 01:00:00 2009-01-05 03:00:00
```